# Запуск установки UEFI Windows 7 x64 c флешки через grub или Linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub, bios, uefi

Имеется ноутбук Samsung на AMD A10 (ЖД GPT), стоит Linux Neon KDE 17.3. Не могу заставить bios видеть установочную флешку в режиме UEFI. Записывал c помощью rufus и вручную с помощью данной [статьи](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2013/12/31/sozdaem-zagruzochnuyu-fleshku-s-windows-7-dlya-uefi-sistemy/) с вставкой загрузочных файлов efi в корень - результат такой же. Есть способ запустить установку с помощью grub или установить все в linux? Нужна как вторая основная система. Хотел в Virtualbox, но не удалось прокинуть видеокарту, непонятная ошибка, не связанная с зависимостями.

P.s.Такая же проблема с дистрибутивом Manjaro, ставил Arch, но возникли проблемы с сетевыми картами, вернулся к Ubuntu-производным.

Answer (score 4):

> стоит Linux Neon

Сделайте наоборот - поставьте сначала винду, а потом - линукс. Так будет автоматически решено много проблем. Только не забудьте, при установке винды, оставить свободный раздел под  линукс.

Comment: Как раз нет возможности поставить систему в uefi режиме, в обычном больше мороки с загрузочным разделом при одновременно разных типах систем. С uefi вплоть до выбора ос загрузки с биоса, что бывает крайне полезно.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась переходом с UEFI на Bios, т.к. UEFI на ноутбуке оказался обрезанным.